# Executing my 3 calls one after the other in my activate function

Tags: breeze, durandal

I work on a project with **durandal/breeze**. I have the following code in my `activate` function:

```
var activate = function (routeData) {

    initLookups();
    var idTran = parseInt(routeData.idTran);
    var idItin = parseInt(routeData.idItin);

    if (idItin == -1)
        idItin = datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(idTran);

    datacontext.getTransportById(idTran, transport);
    datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary);
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I have 3 calls to the datacontext:

- datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport >> *eventually... if (idItin == -1)*
- datacontext.getTransportById
- datacontext.getItineraryById

The problem right now is that each call is not waiting for the previous one to complete before executing.

**My question**: how to proceed to be sure one call is finished before executing the next one? Please note that the first call is inside a condition... I'm thinking of using 'promises' but don't know.

Thanks.

Comment: breezeJS is built with promises. You can chain the async queries. I believe the breeze test files have a sample, but github is have issues with their repo at moment.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part to what you're trying to do is *conditionally* chain three calls together.

You can simply chain multiple calls together using the `then()` method.  However in your case, you need an initial promise to chain when the first condition isn't met.

The `$.when()` method is the trick here, because you can either chain an promise returned by Breeze, or you can chain a "dummy" promise, which is what $.when() gives you.  If the first parameter passed to `$.when` is not a promise, then it returns a promise that is immediately resolved.

If I understand your question correctly, you should be able to write your code something like this:

```
var activate = function (routeData) {

    initLookups();
    var idTran = parseInt(routeData.idTran);
    var idItin = parseInt(routeData.idItin);
    var idtDeferred = $.when();
    if (idItin == -1)
        idtDeferred = datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(idTran);

    idtDeferred
        .then(datacontext.getTransportById(idTran, transport))
        .then(datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary));
}
```

Your code example looks like datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport is supposed to set the idItin var, but I'm assuming that it returns a promise like typical breeze queries.

Comment: I try as you suggested but it doesn't work. For example, let's say I have a list of items and when I click on one item I execute the activate function (the code you suggested) to display the detail view.  The problem here is that the viewmodel use the data from the previous call every time. Any idea? I noticed that if I simply do `return datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary);` the data is OK. But if I use your $.when().... then data displayed comes from the previous datacontext call. Strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Certain parts of your example are unclear to me.

Is `initLookups` asynchronous? If so, do you have to wait for it to complete before performing the other asynchronous steps?

How can `createItineraryDetailTransport` be asynchronous when it returns the integer, `idItin`?

What the heck does `createItineraryDetailTransport` actually do? My guess is that `idItin == -1` when you don't have an `ItineraryDetailTransport` entity yet and therefore don't have the key you need to call `getItineraryById`. If so, you have to restructure the signature of `createItineraryDetailTransport`.

Why does `getItineraryById` have to wait for `getTransportById` when they seemingly have nothing in common?

What are `transport` and `itinerary`? I'm guessing they are accidentally omitted variables that will be set with the results of the async calls within those datacontext methods.

Where is your error handling? What should happen if one of the async calls fails?

These issues must be sorted out before someone can give you a really good answer.

Joseph Gabriel seems to me to be mostly on the right track although I might have written it a little differently

```
...
var transport, itinerary;

var promise = (idItin == -1) ?
      datacontext.createItineraryDetailTransport(aCallBackThatSets_idItin) :
      Q.resolve(); // creates a resolved promise

promise = promise
          .then(datacontext.getTransportById(idTran, transport)
          .then(datacontext.getItineraryById(idItin, itinerary))
          .fail(yourErrorHandler); 

return promise; // don't forget to return the promise!
```

The most important step missing from Joseph Gabriel's suggestion ... and the reason you couldn't make his suggestion work ... is that it neglected to return the promise.

**You must return a promise if you want Durandal to wait before activating the view**.

Comment: (1) Is initLookups asynchronous? Yes but I don't have to wait for it to complete before performing the other asynchronous steps. (2) createItineraryDetailTransport did not return idItin (this is an input parameter) it returns an observable (itinerary). (3) What are transport and itinerary? They are observables I have to fill in before displaying my view. Anyway I added the returned promise as you suggested. Thanks.